# strconv.Atoi() throwing error when given a string

Tags: string, go, atoi, strconv

When trying to use strconv on a variable passed via URL(GET variable named times), GoLang fails on compilation stating the following:

> multiple-value strconv.Atoi() in a single-value context

**However, when I do reflect.TypeOf I get string as the type, which to my understanding is the correct type of argument.**

I have been trying to fix this issue for several hours. I'm new to go and have become pretty frustrated with this problem. I finally decided to ask for help. Any feedback would be appreciated.

```
func numbers(w http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {
  fmt.Println("GET params were:", req.URL.Query()); 
  times := req.URL.Query()["times"][0]
  time := strconv.Atoi(times)

  reflect.TypeOf(req.URL.Query()["times"][0]) // returns string
}
```

Answer (score 70, accepted):

The error is telling you that the two return values from [`strconv.Atoi`](https://godoc.org/strconv#Atoi) (`int` and `error`) are used in a single value context (the assignment to `time`). Change the code to:

```
   time, err := strconv.Atoi(times)
   if err != nil {
      // Add code here to handle the error!
   }
```

Use the [blank identifier](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Blank_identifier) to ignore the `error` return value:

```
   time, _ := strconv.Atoi(times)
```

Comment: Thanks this fixed the issue. It's pretty strange that functions can return more than one type of value in Go though. Does it matter which order time & err are in?

Comment: @deadbeef: multiple returns are one of the basic features of the language. I would suggest at least going through the [Tour of Go](https://tour.golang.org/) to get an idea how the language works

Comment: @cerise It worked for me.

Answer (score 13):

Although this has been answered and the question is quite old, I thought it would be nice to complement the accepted answer.

When a function returns multiple values as in the question, if any of the value is not needed then they can be discarded by using the *blank identifier* `_` as in the following.

```
num, _ := strconv.Atoi(numAsString)
```

This would store the converted number in `num` but discard the error by assigning it to the blank identifier.

But do note that once a value is assigned to `_` it cannot be referenced again. i.e.

```
num, _ := strconv.Atoi(numAsString)
fmt.Println(_) // won't compile. cannot reference _
```